# Why is MongoDB slower on Debian than on Windows..?

Tags: linux, performance, mongodb, io, mongodb-java

I created a small Java application (with Spring Data) to test MongoDB performance with geospatial queries .

```
public class MongoThread {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: MongoThread <nb_thread>");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int nbThread = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfigStandalone.class);
    MongoOperations db = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    for (int x=0; x<nbThread; x++) {
        double lat = Math.random() * 60;
        double lng = Math.random() * 60;
        double radius = 3000 + 50 * Math.random();
        MyThread t = new MyThread("Thread #" + x, db, lat, lng, radius);
        t.start();
    }

    //create1MEntries(db);
}

private static void create1MEntries(MongoOperations db) {
    if (!db.getCollectionNames().contains("Item")) {
        db.createCollection("Item");
    }
    db.indexOps(Item.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("loc"));
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("item" + i);
        item.setLoc(new double[]{Math.random() * 180, Math.random() * 180});
        db.save(item, "Item");
    }
}
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

String name;
MongoOperations db;
double lat, lng, radius;

public MonThread (String name, MongoOperations db, double lat, double lng, double radius) {
    this.name = name;
    this.db = db;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.radius = radius;
}

public void run() {
    long t1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    List<Item> items = db.find(new Query(Criteria.where("loc")
            .near(new Point(lat,lng)).maxDistance(radius/111.12)).limit(100), Item.class, "Item");
    System.out.println(name + " - " + items.size() + " results found around " + radius + " of (" + lat + "," + lng + ")");
    long t2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(name + " - " + (t2-t1) + "ms");
}
}

public class Item {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double[] loc;
}
```

After running the tests multiple times to load data in memory, here are the results I get:

- On my dev computer (Win7 64 bits, i7 860 @2.8 Ghz, RAM 8GB 1066Mhz): For 100 threads, I get all responses in about 500 ms (between 450 ms and 550 ms)
- On my server (hosted by OVH: Debian 6.0 64 bits, i3 2130 2x2(HT) 3.4GHz, RAM 16GB 1333Mhz): For 100 threads, I get all responses in about 1700 ms (between 1600 ms and 1900 ms)

I am not a hardware neither Linux specialist but I was expecting this server to do better than my Windows computer (or at least as good).
I read on several forums that MongoDB was really faster on Linux and that important hardware features were (in that order): RAM, CPU (but Mongo does not use multiple cores) and hard drives.

I increased the max open files (using ulimit -n 99999) because I read that it can slow down MongoDB but it had no effect on the results.

Do you have an idea where the bottleneck come from?

Comment: Do you run it with same java version and identical `JAVA_ARGS`?

Comment: Yes I use Java 1.6 (32 bits) on both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a linux vs windows issue. I mean that i3 processor is pretty low end compared to the beast that i7 is on your windows machine.

If you really want to compare performance between the two operating systems, I recommend to get your setup running on identical hardware..

Comment: Not sure about that when looking at this benchmark: http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/369/Intel_Core_i3_i3-2130_vs_Intel_Core_i7_i7-860.html
My dev computer is becoming old (3 years), the CPU is from the first i7 generation, i3 CPU is higher, and from my readings MongoDB do not use multiple cores.
I will install Debian on my dev computer to compare. But my fears are that the hard disk on the server (hosted by OVH) is slowing down Mongo.

Comment: MongoDB is using Mozilla's SpiderMonkey javascript engine which can execute javascript in only a single thread. However MongoDB is not written in javascript, it is written in C++ and it does use multiple threads. When it comes to javascript execution, it goes into single thread mode but since 2.2 there have been many improvements in the locking of operations so you will see performance improvements with more cores.

Comment: Either way, writing to the database will involve disk operations as well, so if your hard drive RPM or brand is different, the benchmark is useless. If your memory is different, if the available free memory from installed programs is different, even if memory bus speed is different, then the benchmark is NOT about the operating system, it is about the hardware which should have been identical in the first place.

Comment: And I wouldn't use a cheap hosting provider either as they usually use virtualization which is an overhead of its own, as well as locking down the resources that your account is using if you are on a shared hosting plan.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a mismatch in hardware, specifically CPU and I/O performance. There is no reason one OS should be significantly faster than the other.